# Can't open two canvases both showing video in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas, opencv

I'm working on a project where I display a video feed from a threaded queue(which just reads and queues frames from a live webcam), using opencv to look at the image, apply tracking, and generate a threshold image as well. the main video feed gets the image, converts into a PIL image and puts it on the main canvas. the main menu getting the image generates both the image and the threshold mask and places them in class variables. when you open the menu for the mask, it just grabs the variable with the mask, converts it to a PIL image and should display it. both canvas should be able to run simultaneously. however on my PC(which is a standard lenovo idea pad), can't display both, just one or the other, but my friend (with a high end gaming pc) can open both. is there a reason for this, being simply my computer isn't powerful enough? or is there a way to get both to run?

here is the code, edited to higlight code of main concern:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from EyeTrackerClass import *

cobalt = '#0099ff'
grey = '#373737'
black = '#303036'
white = '#ffffff'



class MainScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, video):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.video = video
        self.eyetrackerClass = EyeTrackerClass(self.video)
        user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        self.screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
        self.width = round(int(self.video.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))* 0.75)
        self.height = round(int(self.video.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))* 0.75)
        root.config(bg=grey)
        root.geometry("{}x{}".format(700,450))

        self.videoframe = Canvas(self, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg=cobalt, highlightbackground=cobalt)
        self.videoframe.pack(side=TOP)

        #buttons are packed in the menu


        self.GetFrame()


    def GetFrame(self):
        self.eyetrackerClass.getLandMarksVideo(ThreadCap)
        self.image = self.eyetrackerClass.image
        self.image = Image.fromarray(self.image)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.videoframe.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=self.image)
        self.videoframe.after(10, self.GetFrame)


    def openSettings(self):
        self.settingsWindow = Toplevel(self)
        self.settingsWindow.config(bg=grey)
        self.settingsWindow.title("Settings")
        settingsMenu(self)


class settingsMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, mainmenu):
        Frame.__init__(self, mainmenu.settingsWindow)
        self.config(bg=grey)
        self.pack()
        self.mainmenu = mainmenu

       #more buttons, including button to open mask configuration menu


  

    def openMaskConfig(self):

        self.maskWindow = Toplevel(self)
        self.maskWindow.config(bg=grey)
        self.maskWindow.title("Mask configuration")
        MaskConfig(self, self.mainmenu.eyetrackerClass)

   
    def returntoMM(self):
        self.mainmenu.settingsWindow.destroy()



class MaskConfig(Frame):

    def __init__(self, settingsMenu, eyeTrackerClass):
        Frame.__init__(self, settingsMenu.maskWindow)
        self.pack()
        self.settingsMenu = settingsMenu
        self.eyetrackerClass = eyeTrackerClass
        self.width = settingsMenu.mainmenu.width
        self.height = settingsMenu.mainmenu.height
        self.config(bg=grey)
        self.thresholdval = self.eyetrackerClass.threshold
        self.dilationval = self.eyetrackerClass.dilation
        self.erosionval = self.eyetrackerClass.erosion

        self.screensize = self.settingsMenu.mainmenu.screensize


        #packed buttons for editing threshold values

        self.videoFrame = Canvas(self, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.videoFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.settingsMenu.maskWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.saveSettings)

        self.GetMaskFrame()



    def GetMaskFrame(self):
        self.eyeMask = self.eyetrackerClass.eyeMask
        self.eyeMask = Image.fromarray(self.eyeMask)
        self.eyeMask = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.eyeMask)
        self.videoFrame.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=self.eyeMask)
        self.videoFrame.after(10, self.GetMaskFrame)


        self.settingsMenu.maskWindow.destroy()


root = Tk()
ThreadCap = Threaded_Capture(0)
app = MainScreen(root, ThreadCap)
root.mainloop()
```

if anyone could help that would be great, thank you.

Comment: You know that you can get the screen size using `tkinter`

Comment: yes, that is why were using ctypes that is in EyeTrackerClass to get user metrics which has screen dimensions, this is implemented in the init of main screen and i'm just passing it down

Edit: Sorry, i read that as you can't get screensize, my mistake.

Comment: ok so I improved the code with ```self.videoFrame.update()``` after ```self.videoFrame.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=self.eyeMask)``` in GetMaskFrame, and I get both frames running simultaneously, but when the window is closed i get this error ```_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!mainscreen.!toplevel2.!settingsmenu.!toplevel.!maskconfig.!canvas"```